# To create a jquery.grep tag or to generalize existing grep tag meaning?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just saw a question saying [How can I use jquery .grep() to find an object then update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231490/how-can-i-use-jquery-grep-to-find-an-object-then-update-it). In there, they talk about the `grep` function used in jquery. It does have the tag [grep](/questions/tagged/grep).

However, [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) has around 3K questions UNIX based, as per the [definition of the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/grep/info):

> grep is a command-line text-search utility originally written for
>   Unix.

As I see around 25 questions that have both tags [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) and [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), what's better, to create a [jquery.grep](/questions/tagged/jquery.grep) tag or to make the [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) definition more general?

Comment: [Related discussion on whether or not we should have "hybrid" tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190540/we-should-not-have-hybrid-tags).

Comment: @CodyGray after reading the discussion I see is not very clear what is better to do :D

Comment: Related: [Are tags of language-specific functions appropriate for SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135200/are-tags-of-language-specific-functions-appropriate-for-so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say: remove the tag from those jQuery questions. I feel it's too specific.

(In other words: would we like tags for every possible jQuery [utility function](http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/)? Or generalize commonly known terminology if some library uses the same name for something unrelated? I hope not!)

Comment: I just removed the [tag:grep] from all those questions, adding a link to this question as the "edit subject".

Comment: Nice to see how my opinion is now some kind of a rule ;-)

Comment: Yes, kind of, now people will complain to you :P

Answer (score -1):

As one of the people from [whose question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695798/working-with-arrays-passed-byref) you removed the [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) tag, I can say this is not helpful. `grep` is not specific to one language or paradigm. That's like saying we should remove all [function](/questions/tagged/function) tags from questions (of which there are nearly 30k) not related to C because C used them first (or whatever language). The whole point of a tagging system is to enable the ability to cross-reference topics that may be similar. What if I were looking to see how `grep` was used across the programming landscape? The [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) tag would be supremely useful had you not gone on your escapade to remove them from every non-unix-based question. When the [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) tag is accompanied by another language (in this case, [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)), this is an example of the tagging system succeeding. Want to find [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)[unix](/questions/tagged/unix)? Perform [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grep+unix). Want to find [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)? Search for that [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grep+jquery). Notice how now that second search has been decimated a bit by people like you removing otherwise valid tags. Someone looking for how `grep` works in `jQuery` now have reduced resources because you have removed references to those tags working together.

As for my question, I'm putting the tag back in. I suggest you go back through all the questions you changed and do the same.

Comment: I understand your point. However, as I indicate in the question the [definition of the tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/grep/info) just indicates grep as the UNIX utility. We can do two things: to keep it as it is now, without jQuery's grep, or to update the scope of the tag, including other languages and environments.

Comment: but it's not just jQuery that uses grep. windows uses it, perl uses it, vim uses it... grep is more commonplace than just *nix now. It should represent what it DOES, not where it was invented or what it's used mostly for.

Comment: OK but here in comments we won't solve the problem. I suggest you to suggest an improvement of the tag definition.